# How can I delete a technical indicator without re-rendering the chart?

Tags: anychart

How can I delete a built-in technical indicator without re-rendering the chart in Anychart?

Answer (score 0):

Every technical indicator is a single or set of usual series. So, you can remove them as a series using [removeSeries()](https://api.anychart.com/anychart.core.stock.Plot#removeSeries) and [removeSeriesAt()](https://api.anychart.com/anychart.core.stock.Plot#removeSeriesAt) methods.

For details, check [the sample](https://playground.anychart.com/HBlrcTH0).

Comment: is there a way to remove based on the indicator instance? without having to define an id for each children series (for indicators with multiple series) and then remove them one by one?

Comment: You can use the indicator's API to get its series instances and remove them. For details, check the sample - https://playground.anychart.com/CGLgoXJI/0